# Почему код использующий curses работает неправильно?

Tags: python, curses

У меня есть проект на псевдографике, но мне не нравилась реализация отрисовки. Поэтому я решил использовать curses. Я написал код, но он работает не так, как я хотел.
Вот, что я хотел получить:
https://savepice.ru/full/2019/4/6/0f64ff4eaa1f12957a74f2fd94e18ee9-full.jpg.html

Вот результат:
https://savepice.ru/full/2019/4/6/1882edc14db8bf78

Вот код:

```
def render(self, stdscr):
    bl = "||"
    bt = "=" * (len(self.scene_obj.scene["place"][0]) * 2 + len(bl) * 2)
    cols = 1
    rows = 4

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(1, 1, "Step: " + str(self.scene_obj.scene["count"]))
    stdscr.addstr(1, 3, bt)
    for row in self.scene_obj.scene["place"]:
        stdscr.addstr(cols, rows, bl)
        cols = len(bl)
        cols += 1
        for col in row:
            stdscr.addch(cols, rows, col.symbol, col.color)
            stdscr.addch(cols + 1, rows, " ")
            cols += 2
        stdscr.addstr(cols, rows, bl)
        cols = 1
        rows += 1
```

Comment: Вторая ссылка не открывается. Точнее, открывается, но там нет изображения.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, простую программу, использующую Ваш класс и его метод `render`, и приведите её код здесь. Тогда можно будет её поотлаживать.